# "hostname does not match the server certificate" with aws-sdk-ruby when accessing S3 objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have created a new S3 bucket on aws.
I have a certificate issue I didn't have with the same code on my original bucket.

Here is the code :

```
AWS.config(access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secret_access_key:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region: S3_REGION)
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets[S3_BUCKET_NAME]
@resp = bucket.objects.with_prefix('categories/'+@category.id.to_s+"/")

@resp.each do |item|
end
```

returns the following error when "@resp.each" is executed:

```
hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

- ENV variables were updated with new region and new bucket name
- Uploading images is working
- @resp is returning AWS::S3::ObjectCollection:0x007f815e099d18
- my bucket name doesn't contain dots

Is there something to configurate on AWS S3 to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and I solved it by doing:

```
Aws::S3::Client.new(
:access_key_id => 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
:secret_access_key => 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
:region => 'YOUR_REGION',
:force_path_style => true)
```

Basically, by specifying also a path style.
Let me know if it works!